# Encrypt data for multiple user access

Tags: ruby-on-rails, security, postgresql, encryption, multi-tenant

we have an application, where any registered user can create his own company and grant access for this company to any registered user.
Each company is represented by Postgresql's schema.

Is there a way to en/decrypt users data in schemas without using static key for en/decrypt stored in applications source code? Every user, who was added to company has to have access to company's data.

Thanks for answer

Answer (score 1):

This is a question on which books could be written.  So keep in mind it is a hard problem and you have to take a very complex, long-term approach to these problems.  In essence, no you need a static key, and you don't want to store that unencrypted.  You have several important questions you have to look at:

1. Key management and rotation.  You will probably need the static key to be encrypted per user with public key encryption, and make sure they don't leave their private keys around unprotected!
2. Accidental key disclosure.  So the data on the Pg side is now encrypted.  How might someone get the key?  In short you can't log queries routinely, you may want to set the error level to FATAL in the log, etc.  PostgreSQL doesn't make this easy to prevent.
3. Accidental plaintext disclosure.  This can happen through, say, creating an index of the decrypted data for performance reasons.....  Also connection eavesdropping and much more needs to be looked at.